# Export from excel to multiple text files

Tags: vba, excel

I have an excel sheet with more than a 1000 rows.
Row are divided into groups like there are some blank rows between each group.
Each first row of a group contains the group title.
How can I save each group to a separate txt file with the file name as the same as the title in the first row of the group.
P.s. all the rows are 1 column only

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop statement like ForNext, Do-While, While-Wend.

Then you can use the Open method 
Open "yourTextFileFullPath" For Append As #1

and "print" or write the lines (the values of each cell) in the .txt file with:
Print #1, cell.value

Then you can close it with 
Close #1

And your text file will be filled with te cell values in each line.

Comment: And how to do that ?

Comment: Well.. if you post your file or at least the structure maybe we can take a look at it and help you.